# lists with nested for loops python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested, python-itertools

First off, I'm 100% positive there's some other thing about replacing what I want with itertools. I'm just asking how do I do it. I believe this is not a dupe because it is a specifically tailored question that I couldn't find the answer to on this website that I fully understood or that worked for me.

```python3
for x in range(-200,200):
    for y in range(-200,200):
        for z in range(0,400):
            cube.append(translate(rotate([x,y,z],[0,45,0]), [10,10,50]))
```

Now, I have no idea where to start with replacing this little piece of code, and quite honestly, I don't really understand itertools. All I know is that this is slow and needs to be faster. Don't worry about rotate and translate, those are parts of my 3D program. Cube is also a list that is loaded in later.

Answer (score 0):

So sorry! I figured it out. I was way to quick to ask a question. A little more brain power and searching brought me to this:

```python3
for x,y,z in product(range(-200,200),range(-200,200),range(0,400)):
    print(x,y,z)
```